# spring create bean with merging @ConfigurationProperties prop and application.yml

Tags: spring

I want to read the database credential from the vault server and then create DataSource object.
for handling that I want to read DataSource URL and other properties from application.yml and then added user/pass credential to then to create DataSource object. how can I do it?

my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:db2://...
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    dbcp2:
      test-while-idle: true
      validation-query: SELECt 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
```

my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class Config {
    @Value("${DBUser}")
    private String DBUser;

    @Value("${DBPassword}")
    private String DBPassword;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        return new DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder() 
                .username(DBUser)
                .password(DBPassword)
                .build();
    }
```

I get this exception

```
2020-07-08 15:20:43.005  WARN 76444 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDatasource' defined in class path resource [ir/co/isc/sepam/inquiry/common/InquiryConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDatasource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-07-08 15:20:43.048 ERROR 76444 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Config can do that out-of-the-box and doesn't need additional work, you can just use configuration properties.

Comment: I must get usrname and password from vault server. That mean i can not creat datasource from config file. I just want to find a way to add use and password to what datasource has been addressed in the application.yml file

Comment: Again Spring Cloud Config can do that out-of-the-box it will add a propertysource that retrieves the properties from the vault. How you then configure the datasource is the same as a regular datasource (you don't need a custom configuration).